# Comparing dictionary with integers as both value and key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a method that takes in multiple dictionaries and return the one with biggest value. If some dictionaries share the same max value then it should return the one with bigger key int value.

i.e

```
p1 = {4:5}
p2 = {4:3}
p3 = {8:2}
p4 = {12:5}

def compare(*args):
    #return p4
```

Comment: So...what should the result of `compare(p1, p2, p3, p4)` be?  Also, what have you tried?  Please post your code

Comment: @James it is p4 as indicated in comment

Answer (score 3):

Use `max` with a `key`.

#### Code

```
def compare(*dicts):
    return max(dicts, key = lambda d: max((v, k) for k, v in d.items()))
```

#### Example

```
p1 = {4:5}
p2 = {4:3}
p3 = {8:2}
p4 = {12:5}

print(compare(p1, p2, p3, p4)) # {12: 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code uses the fact that if a dictionary has only one item, that item will be the largest in the dictionary and can be extracted by calling `max()`. Each item is then reversed to put the value in front of the key, and the largest item is computed with another call to `max()`.

```
def compare(*dicts):
    return max([(max(d.items())[::-1],d) for d in dicts])[-1]
```

This function is about twice as fast as the one proposed by Olivier Melançon. (`lambda`s are always slow.)